Blender won't bake fluids
I'm very new to Blender, I'm trying to flood this subway hallway with water but the Bake button is inactive, un-clickable no matter what settings I've changed. Another user even opened my files and they were able to hit the Bake button without changing anything. So I'm really confused as how to fix this on my end. Another issue is that rendering seems incredibly slow, don't know how to make this any faster. Any advice is appreciated.
Files in Drive: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1RZyb080ltdcVuteUk24lMaIKXPNSUiFg?usp=sharing
